# Menu button force close android?

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, android-maps

I have and application that worked fine when you opened the menu button and went to the settings then pushed the back button but when I added the Google maps API into my application the back button force closes the application. Has there been any one else with this same issue? If so how did you fix it? Or does anyone know how to fix this problem?

**Edit:**

My log cat errors on back button force close

```
04-29 16:02:13.155: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16828): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-29 16:02:13.155: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16828): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to            resume activity {www.Freshapp.com.Thumper.html/www.Freshapp.com.Thumper.html.Thumper}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-29 16:02:13.155: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16828):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3128)
04-29 16:02:13.155: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16828):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3143)
04-29 16:02:13.155: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16828):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2059)
04-29 16:02:13.155: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16828):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-29 16:02:13.155: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16828):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-29 16:02:13.155: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16828):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-29 16:02:13.155: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16828):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-29 16:02:13.155: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16828):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-29 16:02:13.155: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16828):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
04-29 16:02:13.155: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16828):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
04-29 16:02:13.155: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16828):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-29 16:02:13.155: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16828): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-29 16:02:13.155: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16828):     at com.google.android.maps.MapActivity.onResume(MapActivity.java:431)
04-29 16:02:13.155: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16828):     at www.Freshapp.com.Thumper.html.Thumper.onResume(Thumper.java:181)
04-29 16:02:13.155: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16828):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1149)
04-29 16:02:13.155: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16828):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3823)
04-29 16:02:13.155: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16828):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3118)
```

**Edit 2**

I took out my map view and the sliding drawer that the map view was in and everything to do with the map and the application gets no FC.

-Thanks

Comment: Please, post an error message from LogCat.

Comment: When you press the back button, the current Activity finishes and the Activity underneath resumes.  The `onResume()` method of `Thumper` is throwing a NullPointerException (line 181).  Can you provide code surrounding what's happening here?

Comment: The onResume() was working until I added the map. Is there something inside the onResume() that I should be putting for the map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I just needed to add a back button function inside of my Setting. Works great now

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    Log.d(null,"In on Key Down");
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
  Intent intent=new Intent(Settings.this,Thumper.class);
  startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```